# Blender Game Asset Creator Tutorial: 5.5 - Unwrapping The Cone

Tags: modeling

In the final unwrap of the section, after sharpening edges, the tutorial asks to unwrap and "follow active quads". I receive a "no active face" error. I feel like I'm missing a fundamental principle here. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you in face mode?

Comment: I am in edit mode. face mode selected.

Comment: I have it set to "face-select", as opposed to vertices or edge select. I'm a noob. Is this what you mean by "face mode"?

Comment: Yes it is. Not sure what your issue is :/

Answer (score 2):

You receive this error because you don't have an active face (quad) selected.

1. Select one face from your mesh to make it an `active face`. It must be a quad (four vertices).
2. Select all faces by hitting <kbd>A</kbd>. You will notice the active face looks a bit different than other selected faces (it's lighter).
3. You can now unwrap with `Follow Active Quads` option.

This is how an active face looks like:

[image: Active face]

Comment: It worked! I was selecting everything at once. So I wasn't getting an active face. Now I can continue with the tutorial. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy I could help - good luck with the tutorial! :)